# What is the best modifer for dps on the Terra blade and Horseman's Blade?

Tags: terraria

What is the best dps modifier for melee weapons specifically Terra blade and horseman's blade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that Legendary is the best modifier for melee weapons, which is what the Terra Blade and The Horseman's Blade are classified as. Quoting from the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Modifiers) (bold emphasis is mine):

> All Pickaxes, Hammers, Axes, Hamaxes and swing Melee Weapons can be reforged with these mods, in addition to the top two categories. (Due to their low base damage, the Wooden Hammer and Copper Axe cannot be affected by modifiers that change their damage by 15% or less.) **The best melee prefix is Legendary**. Note that since the patch 1.1.1 it's no longer possible for a Spear to have any prefix that increases size. This includes Legendary, so the best prefix possible for a spear is Godly. For the purposes of mining and resource collection, the best prefix for tools such as Pickaxes, Hammers, and Axes is Light, which offers the greatest increase in speed.

Legendary grants +15% damage, 10% speed, +5% critical strike chance, +10% size, and +15% knockback, so will give the highest damage per second.

It is also mentioned on the wiki page for the [Terra Blade](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terra_blade) and [The Horseman's Blade](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Horseman%27s_Blade) that the best modifier for each of them is Legendary.

Answer (score -2):

(keep in mind this is not the best for defense and is not used in 1.3) I got my Terra blade to do 221 melee damage using dragon mask, turtle scale mail, and hallowed greaves for armor and I used warrior emblem, destroyer emblem, celestial stone, mechanical glove, and avenger emblem all on menacing. I also used a wrath and rage potion. ( Also keep in mind that this is not advised to be used against most bosses because there's no flying and the defense isn't that great).